# How to integrate sso with ad with a lumen application already using oauth to login?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, lumen

I have an application which uses `OAUTH 2` authentication for login.
Its backend is in PHP( `Lumen` ) and frontend is in Angular.
Now I want to integrate `SSO` with `AD`(Microsoft AD), So when user is authenticated with AD we get his email, so how can i login the user with only email in my application using `OAUTH 2`.